# How to edit the new object-detection-tutorial.ipynb

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

i want to edit the **object_detection_tutorial.ipynb** to use my trained model but the tutorial that i followed online had the old **tensorflow object detection api**

i tried using the old **object_detection_tutorial.ipynb** and continue to follow the tutorial but it didn't show bounding boxes and but when i try the original code where they detect the dog and beach it worked fine using the new **object_detection_tutorial.ipynb** so decided to just edit the new one but i cant really do it correctly

this is what i was saying the new **object_detection_tutorial.ipynb**
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb
and i was following sentdex tutorial which is 2 years ago and alot has changed on the **object_detection_tutorial.ipynb** that was available at that time

what do i need to change in **object_detection_tutorial.ipynb** to be able to use my own trained model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to just import your model in this, in the api indicated below -

detection_model = load_model(model_name)

this has worked for me, hope you have loaded your map file.

Comment: I tried it, but the load_model function searchs and downloads the model_name from the Internet, it given me an error that it cannot find the model from the internet even if i have the model in my directory

Comment: update the function below - def load_model(model_name):
  model_dir = "local path of the saved model"
  model = tf.saved_model.load(str(model_dir))
  model = model.signatures['serving_default']

  return model

Comment: tf.saved_model.load this is the API to load the saved model.